# Testing for unicode escaped strings

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.x

I have an array that looks like this

```
data = [   
    {   'string': u'CN=Willian John sway\xc3\xa9rioGra\xc3\xa7a/emailAddress=will.graca@mail.acme.pt'},
    {   'string': u'CN=E0999999.www.acme.com'}
]
```

Some of the strings contain unicode escaped strings and some don't. I need to iterate over the array and unescape the unicode escaped strings.

I tried doing this:

```
for i in data:
    print unicode(i['string'], 'unicode-escape')
```

However, this always throws an exception for the non escaped string.

Is there an easy way to test for this as part of the iteration?

Comment: Are you sure this is your code? This gives me "TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported" regardless of which string I pass it.

Comment: Why do you want to use `unicode-escape` on this? You can just call `unicode()` without extra arguments on both unicode and str objects. If you still need to check whether something is a unicode string, you can use `isinstance(x, unicode)` to check.

Comment: Throws "an" exception? Which one? What is the actual error message?

Comment: I think you should be encoding with something like `print i["string"].encode("latin-1")`

Comment: No worries, where did the strings come from originally?

Comment: They're from a bunch of X.509 certificates that I'm trying to process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a double-encoded string. It's already been decoded once to create Unicode, but you need to decode it a second time.

To do this, we take advantage of the fact that Unicode takes its first 256 code points from the latin-1 character set. That lets us convert the Unicode string back to a byte string, which we can then decode from UTF-8.

```
print i['string'].encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
```

If this worked for you without the `decode`, it's because your console already understands UTF-8 byte strings directly. If you wanted to assign to a new Unicode string rather than print it, you'd need the `decode`.

Comment: Thank you. This also helped me get to the bottom of my issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be sure from your question, but I'm guessing that you want to convert a Unicode string with non-ASCII characters to an escaped version that uses backslashes before each of the characters that cannot be represented in ASCII. For that, you want:

```
for item in data:
   print item["string"].encode("unicode-escape")
```